# Datatables Date and Time Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use the date and time input in datatables used here https://editor.datatables.net/examples/dates/datetime.html

This is what I've tried

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/materialize.min.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/moment.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples
        var editor;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
                table: '#receivablesLogs',
                fields: [ {
                        label: 'Date:',
                        name: 'date'
                        type: 'datetime',
                        def: function () { return new Date(); },
                        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
                        fieldInfo: 'US style m-d-y date input'
                    }, 
                    {
                        label: 'Invoice Number:',
                        name: 'invoice_number'
                    }, 
                    {
                        label: 'Customer Name:',
                        name:'customer_name'
                    }, 
                    {
                        label: 'Total Amount:',
                        name:  'total_amount'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Due Date:',
                        name: 'due_date'
                        type: 'datetime',
                        def: function () { return new Date(); },
                        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
                        fieldInfo: 'US style m-d-y date input'
                    }
                ]
            } );

            $('#receivablesLogs').DataTable( {
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                columns: [
                    {data: 'date'},
                    {data: 'invoice_number'},
                    {data: 'customer_name'},
                    {data: 'total_amount'},
                    {data: 'due_date'}
                ],
                select: true,
                order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
                bFilter: false,
                bLengthChange: false,
                paging: false,
                bFiler: false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and here is my table

```
    <table id="receivables" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Invoice Number</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                    <th>Due Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>03/31/2014</td>
                    <td>12456</td>
                    <td>Customer One</td>
                    <td>160,000.00</td>
                    <td>04/25/2015</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>02/28/2015</td>
                    <td>12456</td>
                    <td>Customer One</td>
                    <td>160,000.00</td>
                    <td>04/25/2015</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

But I don't know where I went wrong. I imported the correct js files but it doesn't display correctly. This is the output that I'm getting

[image]

Also I don't get what this line `ajax: '../php/datetime.php'` is for. I don't see what is the `datetime.php` that the documentation is referring to.

This is my first time trying datatables so I don't know where I did wrong. I already tried the basic creation of datatables and it worked but I had a problem when I tried to incorporate the date and time input in my codes.

**UPDATE 1:** There exists a server side script like this in the documentation

```
<?php

/*
 * Example PHP implementation used for date time examples
 */

// DataTables PHP library
include( "../../php/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;


// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'users' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'first_name' ),
        Field::inst( 'last_name' ),
        Field::inst( 'updated_date' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::dateFormat', array(
                'empty' => false,
                'format' => 'm-d-Y g:i A'
            ) )
            ->getFormatter( 'Format::datetime', array(
                'from' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                'to' =>   'm-d-Y g:i A'
            ) )
            ->setFormatter( 'Format::datetime', array(
                'from' => 'm-d-Y g:i A',
                'to' =>   'Y-m-d H:i:s'
            ) ),
        Field::inst( 'registered_date' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::dateFormat', array(
                'format' => 'j M Y H:i'
            ) )
            ->getFormatter( 'Format::datetime', array(
                'from' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                'to' =>   'j M Y H:i'
            ) )
            ->setFormatter( 'Format::datetime', array(
                'from' => 'j M Y H:i',
                'to' =>   'Y-m-d H:i:s'
            ) )
    )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

Where should I put this?

Comment: its for the async 'load' function for initial data.

Comment: Did you link scripts from the note below the [code sample](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/dates/datetime.html)? Look for the text "In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:" there.

Comment: So basically, I don't need it if I already manually inputted the data in the table in my example?

Comment: @FerdinandPrantl I already tried it but the output is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I pull this code snippet from the site you provided a link for:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        ajax: '../php/datetime.php',
        columns: [
            { data: 'first_name' },
            { data: 'last_name' },
            { data: 'updated_date' },
            { data: 'registered_date' }
        ],
        select: true,
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'create', editor: editor },
            { extend: 'edit',   editor: editor },
            { extend: 'remove', editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
```

Ajax is a set of techniques to load data dynamically, behind the scenes.

 Some information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX
The link: "../php/datetime.php" is given as an example.
datetime.php is a file you would have to actually make in php.
In this case, datetime.php runs on the back-end, and probably queries some database.

Comment: I see. So basically, I don't need it because I manually inputted the data in my table for now. But I wonder why the basic codes doesn't work.

Comment: When you say basic codes doesn't work. Do you mean why doesn't the data automatically populate your form? Are you asking why you have to enter the data manually?

Comment: No. I mean, Why doesn't my table work the same as the example in the documentation? Because I already did the basic parts except the `Server Script` and `Ajax Load` in the documentation.

Comment: The only dates I see in your post, are exactly in that format. MM-DD-YYYY
I am very confused...

Comment: The dates on my table are in `MM/DD/YYYY` format not in `MM-DD-YYYY`. Also, I've tried changing the initial format to `YYYY/MM/DD` to see if it will actually change to the correct format but it didn't.